# Why does $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(1+\frac{\cos(n\pi )}{n}\right)^{n}$ NOT exist?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

> Why doesn't the following limit exist?
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left(1+\frac{\cos(n\pi )}{n}\right)^{n}$$

I write that because $\cos$ has values in $[-1,1]$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$ this limit can't exists but I don't know if I'm right.

Comment: The expression amounts to $\left(1\pm\frac1n\right)^n$ which tends to $e^{\pm1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

A sequence $a_n$ convergence to $L$ if and only if every sub-sequence convergence to $L$.

Consider the sub-sequences $a_{2n},a_{2n+1}$ of $a_n =(1+\frac{\cos(n\pi )}{n})^{n}$.

Comment: So limit of $a_{2n}=(1+\frac{cos(2n\pi )}{2n})^{2n}$ is different from limit of $a_{2n}=(1+\frac{cos(2n\pi+\pi  )}{2n+1})^{2n+1}$ because $\cos (n \pi)=(-1)^n$ which gives me $1$ or $-1$ and that's why limit doesn't exists, because cos oscilating between $-1$ and $1$.Is my answer correct?

Comment: @DaniVaja yes that's exactly the idea.

Answer (score 4):

$\cos (n \pi)=(-1)^n $. Now look  at the subsequences  $(a_{2n}) $ and $(a_{2n+1}) $.

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Comment: So limit of $a_{2n}=(1+\frac{cos(2n\pi )}{2n})^{2n}$ is different from limit of $a_{2n}=(1+\frac{cos(2n\pi+\pi  )}{2n+1})^{2n+1}$ because $\cos (n \pi)=(-1)^n$ which gives me $1$ or $-1$ and that's why limit doesn't exists, because cos oscilating between $-1$ and $1$.Is my answer correct  ?